# Вывод определенных значений из ключей словаря

Tags: python

Как вывести из словаря только те значения в ключах которых содержится определенное слово. Например "do".

Должно вывести:

> {"Do homework": True, "Do exercise": True}

```
some_dict = { 
      "Do homework": True,
      "Read books": False,
      "Do exercise": True
}

def find(self, word):
    for x, y in some_dict.items():
        if word in x: # не работает
            return x, y
            break
        else:
            return "No such item"
            break
```

Comment: `{k:v for k,v in some_dict.items() if 'do' in k.lower()}`

Comment: Ваш код никак не может вывести `{Do homework": True, "Do exercise": True}`, так как на первой же итерации цикла выполняет `return` и выходит из функции `find`. Даже если бы он что-то нашёл, он вернул бы не словарь из всех найденных ключей, а кортеж из первого попавшегося ключа и значения.

Comment: А что можно использовать в таком случае?

Comment: Если убрать из аргументов ``self``, которое там ни к чему и правильно использовать функцию, то все работает.

Comment: ax да. забыл убрать селф. я просто внутри класса использовал этот метод.

Comment: @godva а можно полный код функции?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def find(dct, word):
    return {k: v for k,v in dct.items() if word in k.lower()}

find(some_dict, 'do') # {'Do exercise': True, 'Do homework': True}
find(some_dict, 'key') # {}
```

Answer (score 1):

"Ламповый" вариант без создания нового словаря, а с редактированием прежнего:

```
def find(dict_, key_):
    for key in dict_.keys():
        if key_ not in key.lower():
            dict_.pop(key)
    return dict_
print find(some_dict, "do")
# {'Do exercise': True, 'Do homework': True}
```